# OpenCV crashes trying to read a video with RELEASE build

Tags: crash, opencv, release, video-capture

Using

```
VideoCapture vcc("someDir/someFile.avi");
```

as the first line in my code (OpenCV 2.x, Win7, VS2010), the execution for RELEASE crashes but the DEBUG works fine .. as slow as expected though. It only crashes when trying to read a video file which means passing a string to the constructor.

The error looks like this:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00905a4d in someName.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.

What I've tried so far:

- Multiple OpenCV2.x versions from SVN
- Different computer
- Different video files
- With or without CUDA, TBB, Eigen, ...

I even created a new project with this single line in it .. still crashes on RELEASE only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright .. Solved my own problem after two weeks.

I changed the project option "With debugging information" to YES in (sub)project opencv_ffmpeg (in solution OpenCV) for the RELEASE build.

Interestingly it works now for "with" and "without debugging" when running .. which both didn't work before.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug - fix is https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/752